# PDF app for creating forms

Tags: pdf

I found cool program PDF Forms Designer (http://pdfformsdesigne.sourceforge.net/) but it can not handle some characters, like: ě,š,ř,ů.

Our company dont want to spend much for Adobe acrobat pro.. Is there some free program/sollution for creating PDF documents/forms.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the free version of [PDFill](http://www.pdfill.com/) for editing PDF's. The full editor costs $20. 
This includes a form tool and says it can handle International languages. The Editor is included as a free Trial if you want to experiment to see if it works for you.

The home page has links to reviews.

Also note that older versions of Acrobat Pro do work in Win7. Acrobat 9+ is fully compatible per MS. ver8 throws an error but just needs a driver manually extracted. Even version 7 will install - just turn off PDFMaker during the install and use a free PDF printer for printing. It throws an error but works fine. Evidently even 6 and 5.1 can be used with Compatibility tweaking. I installed 6 to install a 7 upgrade as it didn't know how to find the prior media.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks better than 5OO euro adobe acrobat pro ;)